# ARIMA model for forecast of wind speed

Tags: arima

I'm trying to forecast the wind speed in order to predict the energy production of a wind tower.

I wanted to use an ARIMA model to do that, I have data from every single minute during 1 year.

So, I followed these steps: http://www.mathworks.com/help/econ/box-jenkins-model-selection.html
in order to create the model, but after the forecast when I try to plot the predicted values, they dont show up as I expect, since the predicted values are almost constant, as you can see in the picture below:

[image]

The code I'm using is this one:

```
Mdl = arima(2,0,0);
EstMdl = estimate (Mdl, f_jan_wind);
res = infer(EstMdl, f_jan_wind);
[jan_forecast, jan_forecast_MSE] = forecast(EstMdl,1440);
total_jan = vertcat(f_jan_wind,jan_forecast);
plot(total_time,total_jan)
```

I would really appreciate some help... Thanks a lot!

Comment: You may be missing a lot on seasonality by using a non-seasonal ARIMA model. You may consider ARIMA with seasonal dummies or Fourier terms as exogenous regressors or SARIMA instead.

Comment: Note that your forecast will converge exponentially towards the unconditional mean/expectation of the process. After some forecasted values the next values will become the constant unconditional mean. See this for more information regarding Matlab and convergence of the forecast: http://se.mathworks.com/help/econ/compare-mmse-and-monte-carlo-forecasts.html